# How can I build a cron-like job executor in Java?

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler

I'd like to develop a Java program that executes tasks registered in a database. The tasks have their own cron-like schedule, which is an object of CronExpression of Quartz Scheduler, and saved in the database after being serialized.

Tasks should be executed anytime according to its schedule, so I think the program should be daemonized, and may be able to be restarted or stopped outside the program (like an usual service beneath `/etc/init.d/`)

I'm studying [the examples of Quartz](https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/generated/2.2.1/html/qs-all/#page/Quartz_Scheduler_Documentation_Set%2F_qs_all.1.058.html%23%20Example%20of%20Quartz)
 and saw the program running continuously even if there's no sleep and shutdown method. This seems nice to achieve my purpose, but I'm not sure if this way can generate a daemon process.

```
// TODO: Retrieve cron format from the database 
Trigger trigger = org.quartz.TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()   
    .withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")   
    .withSchedule(cronSchedule("* * * ? * MON-FRI"))
    .startNow()
    .build();

try {
  sched.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
  sched.start();
  // Thread.sleep(90L * 1000L);
  // sched.shutdown(true);
} catch (SchedulerException e) {
  ...
```

**My question is**

- What is the best way to build a cron job scheduler which runs  continuously on a server?

Thank you in advance, and any opinions or questions would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use Spring to schedule tasks with an executable jar. Here's how to get started https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/

Comment: I cannot determine the schedule on the program, because the schedule is given from outside(web application) and stored in a database. It seems very helpful though... Any ideas?

Comment: What is determining the schedule?

Comment: Thank you for replying! A user can provide a desired schedule from a web application, so the job scheduler program can know the schedule only by seeing the database.

Comment: Hm well that part I'm not an expert at. My only advice is to search how to dynamically set the schedule time. Sorry!

Comment: Okay, anyway I appreciate your comments! I'm going to continue looking for a solution.